# How can I know where are Reads Writes in firebase

Tags: database, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am a new subscriber to Firebase, and I have unexpected reads in my database. And I'd like to know where the readings are done, specifically in which document or collection to identify the problem.
Is there a way to access this information?

Comment: have you checked the server logs?

Comment: No, how can I access it ?